# I can't find the exact error in my code “The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect”

Tags: java, file, drjava

**Please find what am i missing**
here the output: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ur6XOHWJAoJ7aVLRqNP8E39j3Hz9E2T8

```
try
{
  FileReader fr = new FileReader ("residenceData.txt");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr);
  BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter ("resKelantan.txt:"));

  StringTokenizer st = null;
  String dataRow = br.readLine();
  while (dataRow != null)
  {
  st = new StringTokenizer (dataRow, "#");
  id = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
  race = (st.nextToken().charAt(0));
  numChild = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
  income = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
  state = st.nextToken();

   Residence r1 = new Residence (id, race, numChild, income, state);

   if (r1.getState().equalsIgnoreCase("kelantan"))
   {
     pw1.println(r1.toString());
   }

  dataRow = br.readLine();

  }
```

Comment: Please include the error in your question. We Stackoverflow users are lazy and don't like leaving this site to visit external documents

Comment: Have you tried removing the ":" from the output filename? I don't think ":" are allowed in file names on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You better create File first, and then use boolean function File.exists() to find put if this file exists. If so, you can use you code: try{...} and so on. If not, you may call File.createNewFile() function.
For example:

```
File f = new File("somefile");
if (f.exists()) {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
}
```